# Repassing BASH arguments with quotes in to function

Tags: bash, function, arguments, quotes

How to make the function pass 3 arguments instead of four? Quoting arguments in body script don't help me. Example body script of test.sh:

```
func1(){
    echo "Func1: Amount arguments: $#, Passed arguments: $@";
    for i in $@; do
        echo "ARG=$i";
    done;
}

echo "Body: Amount arguments: $#, Passed arguments: $@";
func1 $@;

# quoting with single or double quote
res="";
for i in "${@}"; do
    # try to figure out if quoting was required for the $i:
    grep -q "[[:space:]]" <<< "$i" && res="${res} \"${i}\"" || res="${res} ${i}";
done;

echo "Quoted arguments: $res";
func1 $res;
```

i execute script with next arguments:

```
bash ./test.sh 1 2 "3 4"
```

result:

```
Body: Amount arguments: 3, Passed arguments: 1 2 3 4
Func1: Amount arguments: 4, Passed arguments: 1 2 3 4
ARG=1
ARG=2
ARG=3
ARG=4
Quoted arguments:  1 2 "3 4"
Func1: Amount arguments: 4, Passed arguments: 1 2 "3 4"
ARG=1
ARG=2
ARG="3
ARG=4"
```

I want to get the third argument as "3 4". How to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the arguments on the call to the function `func1` and on the loop inside this function so that the variable expansion does not remove the quotes on your arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash 

func1(){
echo "Func1: Amount arguments: $#, Passed arguments: $@"
for i in "$@"; do                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  echo "ARG=$i"
done
}

echo "Body: Amount arguments: $#, Passed arguments: $@"
func1 "$@"
```

Notice that I have removed the `;` and the end of each line since they are not needed.

Comment: Hmmm... It really works, if quote - "$@". This is the best solution for me, there is no need for additional code. It's strange, but earlier I tried to do it and I did not succeed, but now I checked that everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: Although the other solutions are more generic for nested functions, this should be enough for your code. Notice also the quotes on the `for` loop (these are the ones that you had probably forgotten on previous attempts).

Comment: Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build a list of arguments that require quoting, you must use an array. Syntactic quotes don't nest; inner quotes are treated as literal characters when you expand the parameter.

```
res=()
for i in "${@}"; do
    res+=( "$i" )
done

func "${res[@]}"
```

(The above is equivalent, of course, to `res=( "$@" )` if you aren't doing anything else with the value of `i` except adding it to the array.)